# Icon .ico extention doesn't display in IE or Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

i have gridview buttons for add and delete i used css to display icons for each. it is working fine in firefox but the iccons aren't displayed in IE or Chrome here is my css code

```
.delete {
    display: inline;
    background: url('delete.ico') no-repeat;
    border: none !important;
    background-position: -0px -0px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: none;
    }

.edit {
    display: inline;
    background: url('edit.ico') no-repeat;
    border: none !important;
    background-position: -0px -0px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: none;
}
```

[EDIT]
here is the html buttons

```
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="delete" CommandName="Removal" OnCommand="BtnDelete_Command" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"RowIndex")+";"+Eval("code")+";"+Eval("name") %>' OnClientClick="return not_check1();"  />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="" CssClass="edit" OnCommand="BtnEdit_Command" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"RowIndex")+";"+Eval("code") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Just as a notation. You don't need to put -0px -0px, you just could use 0 0 instead.

Comment: can you show some html as well?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **display: inline;**, try using **display: inline-block;** Keep in mind that you cannot set a height to **inline** elements.

Answer (score 0):

.ico is only supported as a favicon in all browsers.
Use png, gif or jpg instead. 
Or at least a fallback version:

```
.delete {
    display: inline;
    background: url('delete.png') no-repeat; /*fallback*/
    background: url('delete.ico') no-repeat;
    border: none !important;
    background-position: -0px -0px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: none;
    }

.edit {
    display: inline;
    background: url('edit.png') no-repeat; /* fallback */
    background: url('edit.ico') no-repeat;
    border: none !important;
    background-position: -0px -0px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: none;
}
```